# Open documents in Xamarin Forms

Tags: pdf, ms-word, xamarin.forms

I would like opening documents in a Xamarin Forms app possibly without writing platform-specific code.
Documents could be PDF or Word files and I do NOT want to open documents inside the app, rather I want to use the default app: default Pdf Reader and Word (if installed). Any idea?
I am trying by using `Device.OpenUri(new Uri("file:///Assets/pdf-sample.pdf"))` and setting PDF file `Build Action=Embedded Result`, unfortunately without success.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it simply with webview (there goes an example: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/display-pdf/)

Comment: Example project: https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/tree/master/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/Controls/DisplayPDF/

Comment: Or try to find an other solution: https://developer.xamarin.com/en-us/search?q=pdf

Comment: Thank you I saw that solution, but it should only work for PDFs, not word documents...